# Status / welcome message to upgrade should include req warnings

Tags: discussion, notifications

The current status message is: "WordPress 3.2 was released on Monday, July 4. Please remember to update your sites"

It is important to note that the new requirements have changed, notably PHP 5.2.4 up from PHP 4. This is a significant change (albeit a good one), and I for one believe that more attention should be drawn to it. Recommend updating the status to at least include a link to the requirements - there's a good blog post about it: http://wordpress.org/news/2011/07/are-you-ready-for-wordpress-3-2/

Comment: I disagree. Anyone using self-hosted WordPress should know to be responsible for keeping up with the minimum requirements for WordPress or any other server software they're using. I think the upgrade notice is a gentle reminder that users are generally expected to be using the latest version of WordPress, and that WPSE answers will generally assume that the latest version is in use.

Comment: Chip, you're assuming that all WP admins have control over which version of PHP their hosts have. This is not always the case (hosting.com for example has an entire clientbase on 5.1.3 unfortunately). It's very possible for someone to blunder into upgrading their WP out of the capabilities of their own server config. I'm not sure whether the upgrade process checks PHP version prior to committing the upgrade, but even if it does, I can envision edge cases where this won't matter.

Comment: But in that case, even alerting users to the minimum requirements isn't going to help.

Comment: @Tom - Not sure I follow your suggestion. What exactly are you wanting to happen here on this site?

Comment: @Mike - the original thought was to include a very short note encouraging users to also check out the requirements before upgrading by providing a link to the requirements blog post. But I may be coming around to Chip's side of things, especially if Rarst is right that WP will not upgrade itself if that means blowing itself up (a sensible approach).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress does an internal check before updating.  It's been in core since before 3.1.  If your system doesn't support the minimum requirements, **it won't let you update.**

Answer (score 2):

Might a better approach be to create a Community Wiki, that addresses issues regarding updating WordPress from version 3.1 to 3.2?

Comment: This is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure, but I think that WordPress would refuse to update itself if current setup does not meet requirements for new version.

Anyway I tried to change message and first it refused to have two links in it, then I couldn't even restore old message. You made moderator break things, happy? :)

Comment: I say good riddance to it :) I didn't like it there in the first place. I don't like change.

Comment: I'm sorry. There I go, rocking the boat. Again.